# Using samba for svn repository

Tags: svn, samba

Is it a wise idea to access an SVN repository via Samba?

I have read of issues when one does that via NFS - is it the same for Samba?

Comment: Hi Simone. Is there any reason why my answer was un-accepted below? Is there something wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never access your svn repo directly, regardless of its file system. There's very little of use that you can do in there anyway.

You should only access it via its protocols, svn:// or http(s)